# Track Hits using Google Analytics and an ASP.NET web handler (ASHX) page

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, analytics, ashx, google-analytics-api

We are using Google Analytics for our site, but since it uses client script in HTML output we are unable to track hits to any of our ASP.NET ASHX handler pages.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that the server API allows this.

Answer (score 1):

follow [this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/how-to-track-ajax-and-flash-pageviews-in-google-analytics/) example and you should be good to go!

More info can be found [here](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55520) as well.

```
pageTracker._trackPageview("/handler.ashx");
```

Comment: We are evaluating this now.  We are looking into installing the server API.

Comment: It doesn't appear that the server API allows this.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-analytics-data-export-api/browse_thread/thread/d05275d22d34daa?pli=1

Comment: @Carter did you get using server API with latest version?